# How to add description to columns in Entity Framework Core code-first using migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am using Entity Framework Core 3.0 code. How do I add descriptions for columns in entity configuration classes or migrations so that they end up as a column description in SQL Server?

There is a publication for Entity Framework 4.3.1 but I could not do it in the Entity Framework Core.

Comment: It would be easier for others to understand your problem if you share your code.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [HasComment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hascomment?view=efcore-3.1) fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.MyProperty)
    .HasComment("My Column Description");
```

For SqlServer this is mapped to the corresponding table column description.

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion, but an error occurs while creating as migration "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Hi, I've tested it with EF Core 3.1, SqlServer and it worked for me.

Comment: It works only after the table creation is finished, to add comments without the existing table in the database of this error, thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 9):

I'm used [CommentAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.commentattribute).

**Data Annotations** (EF Core 5.0 and above)

```
public class Box
{   
    [Comment("Width in centimeters")]
    public string Width { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Box>()
            .Property(b => b.Width)
            .HasComment("Width in centimeters");
```

Generated SQL script.

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN shipping.box.width IS 'Width in centimeters';
```

My stack EF Core 6.0 and PostgreSQL 14.2.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-comments)